# What is the DOM method to move the mouse over an element?

Tags: javascript, dom

My question is very simple, I want to automate a process where I need to hover over a specific element first, and then click the second element which replaces the first one after hover. So what would be the dom method to use to make mouse pointer hover over that first element with plain javascript?

Comment: You can not literally move the mouse with javascript. However, you can fire a hover event using the [EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventSource) object.

Comment: @WaisKamal ''eventTarget.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSEOVER))'', is this any close to what you mean?

Comment: Somewhat close, yes.

Answer (score -2):

I guess you could use the JavaScript MouseOver event. Maybe have some sample code you want to use?

```
<p id="p" class="p" onmouseover="changElement()">Sample Code</p>
<script>
var el = document.querySelector('p');

function changeElement(){
var newEl = document.createElement('p');
newEl.innerHTML = '<b>Hello World!</b>';
el.parentNode.replaceChild(newEl, el);
}

</script>
```